# Is there any sense in which the City of London Corporation is a corporation wherein other local authorities are not also?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-terms, incorporation, city-of-london

The [City of London Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London_Corporation) includes the word "corporation" in its name. But in the operative sense, are not all other local authorities also such “corporations”?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### All English local authorities are corporations

Comment: Could you provide either a source or more information on that?